# Appium inspector unable to inspect element of iOS

Tags: mobile, automation, appium-ios

I am inspecting a screen on iOS app but it doesn't provide any elements on that screen.

Appium inspector is not providing any objects on that screen. Please help .I am stuck here.If any other way to inspect the iOS screen please suggest.

I am using Appium Desktop v1.9.0 in mac

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZVkf.png

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do following things...

1. Ask your IOS developer to give specific id for the outer container to inner container if present.
2. If you have id for the container and if you are not getting for specific element then ask your developer to add id to that element.

And take a fresh new .app build and then recheck and hope your problem will be solved.